# compiler maven- java with 2 errors in building package

Tags: java, maven, magento

I'm using https://github.com/webdevwilson/magento-java to connect to my store magento with JAVA for integration system. I installed `Maven`, `openjdk-6-jdk`, set up home for java, etc. My information is:
`sudo java -version`

```
java version "1.6.0_36"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.8) (6b36-1.13.8-0ubuntu1~14.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

`sudo mvn -version`

```
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_36, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-43-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

And when i try in folder for package with contains POM.xml file:
`sudo mvn package` or `sudo mvn install` for compile the result is:

```
[INFO] 2 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.511s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Aug 30 19:50:12 EDT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/71M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project magento-ws-client: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /magento-java/src/main/java/com/magi/magento/service/BaseService.java:[27,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : method getMage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPort(java.net.URL)
[ERROR] location: interface com.magi.magento.ws.client.MagentoService
[ERROR] /magento-java/src/main/java/com/magi/magento/service/OrderService.java:[112,44] incompatible types
[ERROR] found   : com.magi.magento.ws.client.SalesOrderListEntity[]
[ERROR] required: com.magi.magento.ws.client.SalesOrderEntity[]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Attention for:

[ERROR] /magento-java/src/main/java/com/magi/magento/service/BaseService.java:[27,34] cannot find symbol

[ERROR] /magento-java/src/main/java/com/magi/magento/service/OrderService.java:[112,44] incompatible types

I have tried to CHANGE version of compiler maven in `POM FILE` here:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But the error persists, what should I do?  And yes, i tried every tip or link when searched in google, nothing solves. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not cross-post: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/294986/22815

Comment: this does not look like a JDK version issue. It seems your magento libraries / dependencies have a version conflict or are just the wrong versions.

Comment: well... first i try to install with jdk-7 but with errors, searching i changed to jdk-6 but still not work

the magento library is installed with MAVEN (mvn commands) but i not get 100% for work.... hum....